# ios push notification development on free apple account

Tags: ios, push-notification

I am very new to ios development. Recently somewhere i read that Apple has now allowed the integration of push notification into the app during development not production on unpaid apple accounts. However, i came across problems while trying to enable the push notification capability for my app on xcode and that makes me wonder if we actually need a paid membership to add the push notification feature on our app.

Comment: What problems did you encounter? Can you share the snippet of code which handles your push notifications?

Comment: If you log in to your developer account at developer.apple.com do you see the option to issue a push certificate?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Problem was not in the code snippet. It just did not allow me to enable the push notification capability on xcode through project->target->capabilities. I am just going to go ahead with my company developer account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We need aps certificates to register device token for getting notifications. So it is not possible in free account.

Comment: Yeah Apparently it appears to be the true case.