# Xcode archive error after successful build of app

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

Currently I'm using `Ionic` Framework and trying to build an iOS mobile App. In order do that I did the following steps:

1. To add the platform,

`$ ionic cordova platform add android`

2.To build the app

`ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"`

3. After it successfully generated `.xcodeproject` file, I imported the file into Xcode.
4. After importing the project, cleaned the project folder in xcode itself.
5. Then I added the `Apple ID` account to my Xcode.
6. After adding the account I'm trying to archive the project, in order to do that I checked the following URL's

[Official Documentation to generate the IOS app](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/)

[Stackoverflow answer to .ipa file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25919449/how-to-generate-an-ios-ipa-file-with-ionic-framework).

6. In the Archiving  process I'm getting the following error:

> error: Your development team, does not support the Push Notifications capability. (in target 'folder')

I tried to rectify it in the following way:

```
DISABLE_PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS=1
```

in the preprocessor macros. Unfortunately it didn't solve my problem.

**I don't have any Apple developer ID**

How to solve this problem, in order to archive the project? Could any one help me in this regard?

I tried all the solutions which are available solutions but they didn't solve any answer. I am stuck since the past **2** days.

Comment: Now i'm using `Xcode 10`

Answer (score 2):

Are you using any plugins that require push notifications?
See [ios push notification development on free apple account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45997514/ios-push-notification-development-on-free-apple-account).

It is not possible to use push notifications without a paid Apple Developer ID.

If not,

Try removing and adding the ios platform again.